# Trying to link two models together in Django: challenges

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to work through linking two models or combining the two in a way that doesn't create an error.

I have one model, which is just a FileField and accepts an uploaded file

```
class FitFiles(models.Model):

    fitfiles=models.FileField(upload_to='PMC/fitfiles' null=False)
```

I have another model that is populated under the same upload function and basically runs some calculations based on the file uploaded

```
class RideSum(models.Model):
    fitfiles = models.OneToOneField(FitFiles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ftp = models.IntegerField()
    norm_power = models.IntegerField()
    intensity = models.FloatField()
    tss = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

Issue with the approach above is that I keep getting an error that fitfiles_id is not found.

I've tried just putting everything under one model, but the issue there is that filefield 'fitfiles' returns a null value and I get a not-null constraint error. Was curious for advice on how to handle.

At the moment I can do things just fine with these two models completely separated (i.e. not trying to link the two), but with the DetailView I need to make sure these always have the same pk and if for whatever reason the primary keys become misaligned between these models then the DetailView becomes a mess of different information.

Happy to post and clarify

Answer (score 0):

The NOT NULL constraint is a column constraint that ensures values stored in a column are not NULL .A column may contain only one NOT NULL constraint which specifies a rule that the column must not contain any NULL value. In other words, if you update or insert NULL into a NOT NULL column, the program will show an error.

Comment: Understood. I was curious if anyone had advice on how to make it not null, like putting in a default value for that column. The value itself isn’t important as long as it would return something

Comment: Generally, during migration, it will ask you if you'd like to replace the value with a default value (I believe the option is 2). If you have already done the migration you may be able to redo it in a multi-stage migration process. eg. add `Null=True` to the field which is having this issue, migrate, then change it to `Null=False`. Then during the second migration you should be given this option again. I am sure there are other ways and I am not positive this is the *best way* but it sounds like it would work.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to cut myself short, I meant to say Unfortunately, the double migration didn't work, got the following: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "fitfiles" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, 295, 228, 0.77, 28.7, 2020-02-15).                                where null is what it appears to assign to what is just a file upload.  Might just have to go with my original plan which was working, or other wise try to come up with another way to refer one model to the other to make sure the detailview stays consistent